# How to compute the cost of an mst graph.

Tags: c, minimum-spanning-tree, igraph

I'm working in C, using the igraph library. I need to get the minimum spanning tree of a given graph stores in a igraph_graph_t type (g). Also I have a igraph_vector containing the weight of each edge (w). The following is my call:

```
igraph_minimum_spanning_tree_prim(&g, &mst, &w)
```

How I can get the weight of each edge in the mst graph? All I need is the cost of mst.

Thanks, Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take the result graph(mst) and sum the weight of the edges.

Comment: I Irakis. Yes. I must sum the weight of the grap. The issue is how I should link the arc of the solution graph with the weight vector. Remember that the weigth vector is ordered following the order of the edges of input grapg. The order of the arc in the mst grapg is different to the arc orthe in the input graph (the graph witch i nidd to calculate the mst)